# Splitting an input log file in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a log file which I need to split using Pyspark Dataframe .Below is my sample log file

```
20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://bpaiddev/dev/data/warehouse/clean/falcon/ukc/masked_data/parquet/FRAUD_CUSTOMER_INFORMATION/rcd_crt_dttm_yyyymmdd=20200523/part-0042-ed52abc2w.c000.snapp.parquet, range:0-27899, partition values :[20200523]
20/06/25 12:19:34 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver
```

From the log sample you can see the first line has more details compared to the second line.
I want `Timestamp, Status ,Message,Range,Value` columns for the first line , for the second line I can have only `Timestamp,Status,Message` columns.

How to apply regex functions to this kind of data ? Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks a lot!

Expected output:

```
    +-----------------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    |         time_val|status|         log_message|         range|               value|
    +-----------------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
    |20/06/25 12:19:33|  INFO|datasources.FileS...| range:0-27899| partition values...|
    |20/06/25 12:19:34|  INFO|executor.EXECUTORd..|              |                    |
    +-----------------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please find the guideline for posting a question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In your case , please post a method to reproduce your sample data, expected output and most importantly, what you have tried until now. It is not a good practice to get the complete coding, done here. We are glad to help when you are stuck somewhere .

Comment: Sorry I am new to this ,So I didn't know exactly how to post. Sorry for my mistakes

Comment: thats ok. removed the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first load a Dataframe with `Timestamp`, 'Status' and all remaining as `String`.

```
input_df=spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("log_lines.log").map(lambda x : tuple([x[0:17], x[18:22], x[23:]])), ["time_val","status","message"])

+-----------------+------+--------------------+
|         time_val|status|             message|
+-----------------+------+--------------------+
|20/06/25 12:19:33|  INFO|datasources.FileS...|
|20/06/25 12:19:34|  INFO|executor.EXECUTOR...|
+-----------------+------+--------------------+
```

Now, you first handle the lines with `Message,Range,Value` as below,

```
input_df.filter(F.col("message").startswith("datasources.FileScanRDD")).withColumn("log_message", F.split(F.col("message"), ",")[0]).withColumn("range", F.split(F.col("message"), ",")[1]).withColumn("value", F.split(F.col("message"), ",")[2])..drop("message").drop("message").show()


+-----------------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|         time_val|status|         log_message|         range|               value|
+-----------------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|20/06/25 12:19:33|  INFO|datasources.FileS...| range:0-27899| partition values...|
+-----------------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Then you may handle the other line which just has message,

```
input_df.filter(~(F.col("message").startswith("executor"))).show()

+-----------------+------+--------------------+
|         time_val|status|             message|
+-----------------+------+--------------------+
|20/06/25 12:19:33|  INFO|datasources.FileS...|
+-----------------+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs .So for the second line the range and the value column becomes null. Am I right ?